# How to convert the Full UTC time to yyyymmdd format using javascript

Tags: javascript

here how can i convert the

```
 [Sun Jul 15 2018 17:48:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jul 22 2018 17:48:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)]
```

to   20180715  using javascript

here  a variable named **DateData** is storing the above two dates
DateData:Date[];

After selecting the from the datetime picker i storing the data in the DateData

now i am trying to convert the variable using DateData.toISOstring or DateData.toDate() also not working displaying as unable to convert the dataData to  Date Format

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: actually i generated a range of date from the date picker and those are the above 2 dates and now i am trying to convert those dates into 20180715   format  but im getting like unable to convert

Comment: Could you add the code that you’ve tried and the error message?

Comment: So give a [mcve] of that.

Comment: @Aankhen could u please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
function sqlDate(dat)
{
  return dat.toISOString().substr(0,10).replace('-','');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go. :)

```js
function convertDates(dateArr) {
  var newDateArray = [],
      dateObj;
  for (var i=0; i<dateArr.length; i++) {
    dateObj = new Date(dateArr[i]);
    newDateArray.push(dateObj.getFullYear() + '' + dateObj.getMonth() + '' + dateObj.getDate());
  }

  return newDateArray;
}

var dateArr = ['Sun Jul 15 2018 17:48:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', 'Sun Jul 22 2018 17:48:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'];

console.log(convertDates(dateArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatDate(date){
    if(date instanceof Date) date = new Date(date);
    var fullZero = s => s.toString().length ===1 ?'0'+s :s.toString();
    return `${date.getFullYear()}${fullZero(date.getMonth()+1)}${fullZero(date.getDate())}`;
}

formatDate(new Date) // -> "20180722"
```

If you have an array of Date, use `dateData.map(formatDate)` to format it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the `"T"` like this snippet:

```js
var d = new Date();
// => d.toISOString() show 2019-02-01T06:38:21.990Z
console.log(d.toISOString().split("T")[0].replace(/-/g, ''));
```

or you can use a JavaScript library called **[date-and-time](https://github.com/knowledgecode/date-and-time)** for the purpose.

```js
let now = date.format(new Date(), 'YYYYMMDD');
console.log(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/date-and-time/date-and-time.min.js"></script>
```